# How do psychometric employee screening tests work and how can students tackle them?

Tags: measurement, test, psychology

I've given several psychometric tests for various companies without giving it a second thought but now that I think about it, it seems quite deep and fascinating. I'd like to understand, if anyone care to explain, what do these tests try to measure, how can one create such a test to use in teams & hiring processes and finally, can someone 'prepare' for a psychometric test to do better? if yes, how? (Both in advance as well as when only a few hours are remaining.)

Thanks!